# Kubuntu 18.10 - How to make Window List larger on Task Manager (Panel)

Tags: kubuntu, kde

I Disabled **Present Window**

```
System Settings > Desktop Behaviour > Desktop Effects > (Disable) Present Windows
```

I also disabled Taskbar (Panel) Tooltip

```
Right Click Panel > Configure Icon-Only Task Manager > Uncheck Show tooltips
```

So, When I click on an Group Icon on the task manager, it probably shows `Window List`.

[image]

How can I make this list larger so that it gives full details.

Something Like -

[image]

**PS:** I made up the second image from Task Switcher<sup>*</sup> to give a rough idea.

---

<sup>[*] <sub>System Settings > Window Management > Task Switcher > Informative instead of Breeze</sub></sup>

Comment: When I click dolphin on task manager, I only want to show opened dolphin windows. I know task switcher shows all the apps. It was a wrong analogy. I only used it for the looks. Thanks for making it clear. Can you please suggest a title for the question? I think the terms I used are not totally KDE friendly.

Comment: My desire is to have larger font size and padding around each line. Also would like to see the full text. For example, in the first Image it says `Downloads - Dolph...`, it should say, `Downloads - Dolphine`. I noticed it only cut the application name.

Comment: I checked, it is the `System Settings > Fonts > General : ` which affect the task manager. However, it affect the whole system as well.

Comment: I changed Dolphin Preference `Startup > Show full path in title bar`, so that it shows full path in `Window List`. It is working fine. If only I could apply padding around each line, increase the fonts and show full line without cropping then it would have been great.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a plasma widget available, at least in Kubuntu 18.04, that is at the bottom of the widget list you see when you click on ☰ at the bottom or extreme end of your panel:

Window List widget:

[image: Window List widget]

And, after you install it, clicking on it ( (outlined in red)) shows something like this:

[image: list of open windows]

But even with this widget, items longer than a fixed number of characters are terminated with an ellipsis (…).

I don't know if you'll find this more convenient.

Comment: It would be nice if I could just change the window list width. I have a huge monitor and it just take part of the screen.